# 7.1 surround sound 20.04 steelseries arctis 7

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

see also my question here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586779/7-1-surround-sound-linux-ubuntu-steelseries-arctis-7 which got no attention (copied below)

When connecting my Arctis 7, I see in my settings->audio->test only front left and front right speakers. Same in alsamixer. I've changed the default sample channels setting as said here https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, but it didn't seem to change anything.

I've also found this question: How do I configure PulseAudio for 7.1 Surround Sound over HDMI? but I can't seem to run that line for my setup (tried replacing hdmi with surround71, and with a few other things in this list: https://gist.github.com/JoranDox/08658296d01bb4c78e6ed5be815f2a6c )

resulting in

$ pasuspender -- speaker-test -D surround71 -c 8 -m FL,FC,FR,RR,RRC,RLC,RL,LFE

speaker-test 1.2.2

Playback device is surround71
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 8 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Channels count (8) not available for playbacks: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
$ pasuspender -- speaker-test -D surround71:CARD=S7,DEV=0 -c 8 -m FL,FC,FR,RR,RRC,RLC,RL,LFE

speaker-test 1.2.2

Playback device is surround71:CARD=S7,DEV=0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 8 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Broken configuration for playback: no configurations available: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
They say to use DTS Headphone:X on windows for 7.1 surround, is this not possible on linux? I've tried running SteelSeries Engine under wine but it didn't work out (tried 5.0, 5.4 and 5.8). I've got a windows dual boot where it does work, so if I need to get some info from there that's also possible.

Any leads?